# Need help to construct a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to search and replace in a string using regex. I know this is common knowledge to many of you, but for me its very confusing.

Sample:

```
string beforeReplace = "Text sample &=xxx where some &=123 is missing";

string afterReplace = "Text sample &=xxx; where some &=123; is missing";
```

The strings "&=xxx" and "&=123" should be replaced by "&=xxx;" and "&=123;" by searching for "&=", jump 3 chars to the right, and add a ";".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you need a regular expression for this? "Search for &=, jump 3 chars, add ;" sounds very code friendly...

Comment: I think so since there may be more than one hits per line (its not a simple replace).

Comment: I would use a while loop, when you don't find a match then simply exit loop anyway Jon's answer made it pretty straightforward with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "&=.{3}", "$0;");
```

It's not complicated really -- you search for `&=.{3}` which means "`&=` followed by any three characters" and replace with `$0;` which means "whatever you matched followed by a `;`".

Since you will be working with regular expressions you should also devote some time to understanding them. There is [good reference material](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) available for free.

Comment: Nice - there is one thing though - is it possible to detect if the ";" is already there and then don't add another ";" ??

Comment: @PeterLarsen'CPH': Yes, with the expression `"&=.{3}(?!;)"`. The added part is negative lookahead, explained in the reference link I gave.

Comment: Thanks, I will try AND look follow the links...